# How can I x11 forward from docker to the host inside a virtual machine then to the localhost?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Here is the scenario

```
program (inside container) -> virtual machine -> localhost
```

I'm using a mac os as a host and boot up a virtual machine using virtual box. Inside virtual box, I boot up a container containing a program with GUI. Is there a way to do X11 forwarding to my mac os host (I want to see the GUI from mac host)?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think "localhost" is?  The container, the VM, and your physical host all think it's 127.0.0.1 but they each think it means themselves.

Comment: I mean "physical host".